# How do you add the something in http://www.something.webname.com

Tags: domain, url

How can I add this extra part and what does it mean?

www.**SOMETHING**.domain.co.uk

Comment: Add it where? DNS control? Web server? Perhaps combination if both?

Comment: Bit of both :-)

Comment: Well then update your question to explain in greater detail what exactly you’re trying to achieve. Also include involved services and software.

Comment: It is pretty clear what I am asking... Everybody seems to understand. @slhck

Comment: Yes, clearly. That’s why the question is on hold...

Comment: stay out of it @DanielB

Comment: It's not to me. Do you have a domain you own that you need to manage? Do you have a web server that you need to configure to listen to a given domain? If you could just clarify that part, you'd get a more specific answer.

Comment: I have my answer though. So it must have been a good enough question?

Comment: Well, it's not clear if it even applies to our scope. Domain management has nothing to do with computer software or hardware, which makes it off topic here, and possibly on topic for [Webmasters.SE]. Then we could migrate it (provided the question is clarified). If on the other hand you need to configure a server, that'd be within our scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a subdomain and is typically done in the A record where your host your DNS records (quite often, the same place where you register the domain name)

Even `www` can be considered a subdomain.

You should be able to create new A records, simply enter the name of the subdomain and point it to the relevant IP address.

Then, your web server can be set up to redirect it to the relevant directory.

From memory, there are restrictions though such as you may not be able to start the subdomain name with numbers.